# How to show updated ASP.NET page to user before MsgBox is shown?

Tags: asp.net

When user presses a button, I change the button's .backColor, and then popup an OK MsgBox prompt.

But the .backColor isn't displayed until after the popup OK is pressed.  I need it displayed before.

The only solution I can think of is to replace MsgBox with page UI controls:  an OK button and label that shows message.

Answer (score 0):

Probably helpful to post your code; but I'd suggest a javascript attachment to the onClick() event of the button to handle that as a css change. Again though, hard to say without code to see what's happening.